# Javascript - Algolia autocomplete blur event listener not working

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an input field for which I use algolia autocomplete, which I show on clicking of a button, and I am trying to hide the input field again when the field is not focused anymore. This is the field:

```
<span class="button-search">
    <input type="search" name="q" class="input search-input aa-input-search" placeholder="Search ..."  value="{{ Request::get('q') }}">
</span>
```

And this is the js code:

```
function expand(action) {
    searchContainer.classList[action]('expanded');
}
button.addEventListener('click', function() { expand('add');input.focus(); }, false);
input.addEventListener('blur', function() { expand('remove') }, true);
```

It works fine if I remove the algolia class, but for some reason it is not working when I am using algolia autocomplete for that field, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `autocomplete.close()` function on `blur`

ref: https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#standalone-1

Comment: But, the problem is that the event listener is not triggered, so I can't use that

Comment: I think you can do `autocomplete(/*...*/).on('blur')`